# Exceptions not propagating up automatically in Dart

Tags: dart, async-await, try-catch

Edit:

This was a false alarm. See my answer post below for details.

Original post:

I've been hitting my head against this for a while now, so I made some test code to confirm the behaviour that I'm seeing.

I have this code, where there's a chain of async methods, and one of them deep down is throwing an error.

```
Future test() async {
  await test2();
}

Future test2() async {
  await test3();
}

Future test3() async {
  await test4();
}

Future test4() async {
  throw "a test failure";
}
```

Then, elsewhere in an async method, I made this call:

```
try {
  await test();
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

What I'm seeing is that my catch statement isn't being hit.

Now if I instead add a catch within each test method and rethrow the error, instead now the code flows and my topmost catch statement works:

```
Future test() async {
  try {
    await test2();
  } catch (e) {
    print("test");
    throw e;
  }
}

Future test2() async {
  try {
    await test3();
  } catch (e) {
    print("test2");
    throw e;
  }
}

Future test3() async {
  try {
    await test4();
  } catch (e) {
    print("test3");
    throw e;
  }
}

Future test4() async {
  throw "a test failure";
}
```

What am I missing? Why doesn't my topmost catch statement catch the error unless I explicitly catch and rethrow the error at each level?

For reference, I'm currently running this version of Dart:

Dart SDK version: 2.12.3 (stable) (Wed Apr 14 11:02:39 2021 +0200) on "macos_x64"

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. For an example such as this, it should include a main method. I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so in the end, it looks like the catch statement was working. The confusion was around how the debugger in VS Code was reacting to it.

When individual try/catch statements are included the debugger flows through the code and ignores the exception. However, when there's only the try/catch at the topmost level, VS Code halts at the exception.

[image]

However, if you tell the debugger to continue, it will then hit bubble up to the outer catch statement.

So in the end it's a false alarm and unintuitive behaviour from my debugger.